# Log4Net on Azure

Tags: azure, logging, storage, log4net

I've tried everything I can possibly find online to get log4net working with Azure but haven't had luck yet as most of the documentation is extremely outdated. If anyone has this working with the latest Azure SDK and version of Log4Net, and can push me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

It seems like there are a ton of different ways to do this, but I haven't yet gotten it to append to a table, blob, or database like many of the examples suggest.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using and any errors you're receiving.

Comment: Where are you trying to log to? Azure SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use SQL or Azure SQL with log4net in an Azure website or web role:

Create the log table in your DB:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Log]    Script Date: 4/3/2015 6:32:43 PM 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Level] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [RemoteHost] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Cookie] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [QueryString] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Referrer] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [RequestMethod] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ScriptPath] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [UserAgent] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Domain] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CustomBlob] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_11579ccd-53dd-4bcc-a813-cb4cfb7b6b88] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Modify your web.config file:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data,  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="...[your connectionString]..." />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Level],[Message],[Exception],[RemoteHost],[Cookie],[Url],[QueryString],[Referrer],[RequestMethod],[ScriptPath],[UserAgent],[Domain],[CustomBlob]) VALUES                     (@log_date, @log_level, @message, @exception,@remote_host,@cookie,@url,@query_string,@referrer,@request_method,@script_path,@user_agent,@domain,@custom_blob)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@remote_host" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{RemoteHost}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@cookie" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{Cookie}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@url" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{Url}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@query_string" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{QueryString}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@referrer" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{Referrer}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@request_method" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{RequestMethod}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@script_path" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{ScriptPath}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@user_agent" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{UserAgent}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@domain" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{Domain}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@custom_blob" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CustomBlob}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="All" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Did you find any performance issues with log4net + azure sql and are there other considerations one should consider? I'm heavily leaning towards using this but thought I'd ask someone who's already been down this path. thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Nothing noticeable.  You might also want to look at Application Insights - It has good features for logging exceptions and other data.